Representing the finite field as $\{i*g+j\}$ where $g$ is a generator
This question arose from my thoughts on why the size of a finite field is always a prime power like $p^n$.
First, $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a field, and $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z -\{0\}$ is a cyclic group under the multiplication operation, by the following theorem:

1) A polynomial of degree $n$ over a field has at most $n$ roots in that field.
2) $\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) = n$.

Assume that there exists a finite field $F = \Bbb F_{p^2}$ of $p^2$ elements. Then, all elements of $F$ are roots of $x^{p^2}-x=0$. By the same argument as above, there exists a generator $g$ in $F$, and we can represent this field in the following manner: $F = \{ig + j | i,j \in \Bbb F_p\}$.
By the closure property, $ig+j$ is an element of $F$, and for two different $(i,j),(i',j')$, $ig+j,i'g+j'$ are different: if $ig+j=i'g+j'$, then $(i-i')g=j'-j$; first, if $i=i'$, then $0\cdot g=j'-j=0$, and $j=j'$, a contradiction to the pairs not being equal. If $i \not = i'$, then $g = (i-i')^{-1}(j-j')$ is an element of $\Bbb F_p$, another contradiction. So all $ig+j$'s are elements of $\Bbb F_{p^2}$, and there are $p^2$ elements, so we can represent the field like: $F=\{g,g^2,\ldots,g^{p^2-1}\}\cup\{0\}=\{ig+j | i,j \in \Bbb F_p\}$.
My question is the following:

For a fixed generator $g$ of $\Bbb F_p^2$, can we find $(k,l)$ s.t. $g^m=kg+l$ for $m=1,\ldots,p^2-1$?

I think I would like to find a formula for the function $f$, where $f(m)=(k,l)$. I have some progress in this problem:

Assume that $g^2=ig+j$. Then $g^p=-g+i$ and $g^{p+1}=-j$, where $-j$ is generator of $\Bbb F_p$.

Additionally I think that $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ can be represented like a vector space. Does there exist an algorithm to find $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ s.t. $\Bbb F_{p^n} = \{i_1a_1+\ldots+i_na_n | i_1,\ldots,i_n \in \Bbb F_p\}$.
I'm not good at my English, so i would welcome any comments and questions. Thank you!

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

@dietrich_burde thanks sir, i will eidi it right now

To understand why finite field has its cardinality being a power of prime, we may suppose that $F$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$ with $|F| = p^nq,(p,q) = 1$, then as $F$ is a finite group with respect to addition, the classification of finite Abelian groups tells us that $F = G \times H$, with $|G| = p^n, |H| = q$, so clearly there is some element $y \in H \subseteq F, y \neq 0$, such that $q \cdot y = 0$.However, Bezout's theorem ensures that $ \exists a \in \mathbb{Z},$ such that $ aq = 1 \mod p$, thus $1 \cdot y = aq \cdot y = 0$, a contradiction.
For your question about generators,since we are picking $g \not \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and $g^{p^2} =g$, we may assume that $g$ is a zero of some polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f|x^{p^2}-x$. We may assume that $f$ is irreducible so that it is minimal in its degree and this gives you the desired relation. Furthermore, if you know of field theory or Galois theory, then you'll know that this irreducible polynomial is of degree $2$ and in fact $\mathbb{F}_{p^2} = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f)$.
Your idea about vector space is also right. In your simplest example $\{1,g\}$ is a $\mathbb{F}_p$-basis. For higher orders this also works but a bit trickier. For the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, there is some element $x$, such that $x^{p^k} = x$ if and only if $ n |k$. You can use this $x$ as a generator. However, this time the basis is no longer $\{1,x\}$. You might need some results in field theory, but you can find another irreducible polynomial $g$ of degree $n$ with $g(x)=0$ and then $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} = \mathbb{F}_p[t]/(f)$. In order to generalize $\mathbb{F}_p[t]/(f)$, you need to generalise all polynomials with degree smaller than $n$, hence the basis in this case is $\{1,x,...,x^{n-1}\}$.

Thanks, i will try to comprehend what you explain.
